# performSelectorOnMainThread Embedded in didUpdateToLocation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to call a method from the didUpdateToLocation method like below. In my buttonUpdate method, I am updating the interface, and am trying to avoid the lag that would be caused if I were to put the block of code directly in the didUpdateToLocation method. For some reason, the code below is causing my app to crash. Does anyone know why? Thank you!

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation 
*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {  

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(buttonUpdate:) withObject:nil 
        waitUntilDone:NO];   
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you put the crash log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I see right away is that you're calling your method via this selector:

"`buttonUpdate:`"

The colon in that method signature implies there's some *object* that's supposed to be passed along (e.g. `"- (void) buttonUpdate: (NSString *) maybeAString`".  And you're passing nil, which may be the problem (if the method is expecting something real - and not nil - to be passed along).

Comment: aww (blush). I am not awesome. I just like helping to set people on the right path to success.

Answer (score 1):

"buttonUpdate:" means you have a method with name buttonUpdate and has parameters. You are sending 'nil' in 'withObject' in your performSelectorOnMainThread call. Either you are getting exception due to nil parameter or your method doesn't take any argument.

use this line, if your method doesn't take any arguments:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(buttonUpdate) withObject:nil 
    waitUntilDone:NO];
```